# google mock private and afx methodes

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a problem,

I will test this public function:

```
bool FeatureManager::isFeatureActivated(CString section, CString key)
{
    bool isActivated = false;
    char  returnedString[MAX_PATH] = _T("");
    CString  path = getPath();
    path.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
    path += "InternFeatures.ini";
    
    if (GetPrivateProfileString(_T(section), _T(key), "", returnedString, sizeof(returnedString), _T(path)))
    {
        CString currentValue = returnedString;
        if (currentValue == "{ja}")
        {
            isActivated = true;
        }   
    }

    return isActivated; 
}
```

the `getPath` is a private method, now the first question how can I Mock the `getPath` method.

```
CString FeatureManager::getPath()
```

and the `GetPrivateProfileString` is a WinBase.h method, and this is the second question, how can I mock this?

Comment: You may not mock the free function `GetPrivateProfileString`, but you may add a virtual method that invokes `GetPrivateProfileString` and mock this new method.

Comment: oh, can you give me an example?

Comment: @j The examples are in the duplicated questions.